# Regex greedy to pull only required information

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have one scenario

```
CF-123/NAME-ANUBHAV/RT-INR 450/SI-No smoking/SC-123
```

Regex should be compatible with java and it needs to be done in one statement.
    wherein I have to pick some information from this string.which are prefixed with predefined tags and have to put them in named groups.

```
(CF-) confirmationNumber = 123
(Name-) name             = ANUBHAV
(RT-) rate                = INR 450
(SI-) specialInformation = No smoking
(SC-) serviceCode        = 123

I have written below regex:
^(CF-(?<confirmationNumber>.*?)(\/|$))?(([^\s]+)(\/|$))?(NAME-(?<name>.*?)(\/|$))?([^\s]+(\/|$))?(RT-(?<rate>.*?)(\/|$))?([^\s]+(\/|$))?(SI-(?<specialInformation>.*?)(\/|$))?([^\s]+(\/|$))?(SC-(?<serviceCode>.*)(\/|$))?


There can be certain scenarios.
**1st:** CF-123/**Ignore**/NAME-ANUBHAV/RT-INR 450/SI-No smoking/SC-123
**2nd:** CF-123//NAME-ANUBHAV/RT-INR 450/SI-No smoking/SC-123
**3rd:** CF-123/NAME-ANUBHAV/RT-INR 450/**Ignore**/SI-No smoking/SC-123
```

there can be certain tags in between the string separated by / which we don't need to capture in our named group.`enter code here`
    Basically we need to pick **CF-,NAME-,RT-,SI-,SC-** and have to assign them in **confirmationNumber**,**name**,**rate**,**specialInformation**,**serviceCode**. Anything coming in between the string need not to be captured.

Answer (score 0):

To find the five bits of information that you are interested, you can use a pattern with named groups, compiling the pattern with the regex Pattern

Then, you can use the regex Matcher to find groups

```
String line = "CF-123/**Ignore**/NAME-ANUBHAV/RT-INR 450/SI-No smoking/SC-123";

String pattern = "CF-(?<confirmationNumber>[^/]+).*NAME-(?<name>[^/]+).*RT-(?<rate>[^/]+).*SI-(?<specialInformation>[^/]+).*SC-(?<serviceCode>[^/]+).*";


// Create a Pattern object
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

// Now create matcher object.
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
```

After that, you can work with the matched groups:

```
if (m.find( )) {
    String confirmationNumber = m.group("confirmationNumber");
    String name = m.group("name");
    String rate = m.group("rate");
    String specialInformation = m.group("specialInformation");
    String serviceCode = m.group("serviceCode");

    // continue with your processing

 } else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
 }
```